# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. Android resources linking failed

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Encountering this error while trying to build appbundle.
I am using VS Code for my build. I could use Android Studio, but first I wanted to make sure I can fix this using VS Code.

Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable
Tools • Dart 2.14.4

my build.gradle-file below:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.waaiburg_app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05'
}
```

Error:

```
Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33377b87c8e52a3339eefad7aba2d7f9\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

     C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33377b87c8e52a3339eefad7aba2d7f9\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:16:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.

     C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33377b87c8e52a3339eefad7aba2d7f9\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:17:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.

     C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33377b87c8e52a3339eefad7aba2d7f9\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:18:5-101: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.

     ...

     C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33377b87c8e52a3339eefad7aba2d7f9\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:8:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.

     C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33377b87c8e52a3339eefad7aba2d7f9\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:9:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             69,9s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

build.gradle: I tried changing targetedSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion from 30 to 29, but I'm not sure how to find the Android-sdk I'm using so they match.

I'm also looked through some of the files that gave the errors, result: I also can't find an entry in the xml-files with the given value (for example: ndroid:color/system_neutral1_1000 was not in the give xml-file)

I had some errors with Gradle before (assembleDevdebug and assembleDebug-task). My Avast anti-virus was preventing some files to be accessed. But i'm sure this isn't the case for this problem.

I have installed:

- Android 11 (API: 30);
- AndroidR Preview (API: R);
- Android 9.0 (API: 28);
- Android 8.1 (API: 27);
- Android 8.0 (API: 26);
- Android 5.1 (API 22) and
- Android 5.0 (API 21).

Is it recommended to delete all but one android version  or  is this not a problem?

What I noticed is that all the files are in a folder named ...\values-v31... Could this indicate that I need to install API level 31? I don't want to install another SDK, because my drive is filling up quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed sdk level 31 via SDK manager from Android studio. I also created a Virtual Device (VD) with AVD-manager. While creating, I also downloaded the x86 image from API level 31, so I didn't had to worry about missing files. (see image)

I also upgraded my CompileSdkVersion and targetedSdkVersion to 31 in the build.gradle-file.

Encountered another error while trying to run and debug on my new VD. I fixed that by enabling [multidex support](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support) . But still had an error trying to build my app on the new virtual device, so I made another virtual device with a lower (Android 11, API level 30) to test my app, and it worked!

My appbundle was successfully built. Onto the next steps of releasing the app to Google Play! Wish me luck.

[Screenshot of SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR2eE.png)

[Screenshot of AVD Manager, while creating virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHUL8.png)